# SQL Group by attribute and show results if there is more than one in that group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, **testing**, with the attributes: **id**, **fruits**.

We have the following contents in said table:

```
id, fruits

1, Apple
2, Banana
3, Apple
```

I would like a query that groups these by the fruits (Apples in one group, Bananas in another) and returns if there is more than 1 in that group.

So, for the example above, the query should return:

```
1, Apple
3, Apple
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM testing 
GROUP BY 'fruits'
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 'id'
```

This query only returns one of the apples.

Thanks for any help!
Toby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to find the duplicates, and an outer query that gets your rows;

```
SELECT * FROM testing 
WHERE fruits IN (
  SELECT fruits FROM testing 
  GROUP BY fruits HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
ORDER BY id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/130e7/2).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the most efficient way to do this is probably to use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from testing t
where exists (select 1
              from testing t2
              where t2.fruits = t.fruits and t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `testing(fruits, id)`.

Comment: May you please take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246530/how-can-i-put-a-condition-on-the-way-of-join)? To be honest I asked my question just to see *your opinion* about it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to join back to the table in order to get the desired result:

```
   SELECT t1.*
   FROM testing AS t1
   JOIN (
      SELECT fruits
      FROM testing 
      GROUP BY fruits
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ) AS t2 ON t1.fruits = t2.fruits
   ORDER BY t1.id
```